# How to get SecIdentity after SecCertificateCreateWithData and SecItemAdd?

Tags: ios, swift, certificate, ssl-certificate, keychain

I was given a .cer file which needs to be used to connect with the server properly. At first SecCertificateCreateWithData crashed, so after research, I ended up converting .cer file to der format (openssl x509 -in cert.cer -outform der -out certder.der), and then iOS seemed to accept it.

I need to get SecIdentity object, however, there seems to be a problem:

```
let cerPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "certder", ofType: "der")

    let data: NSData = try! Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: cerPath!)) as! NSData
    let cert: SecCertificate = SecCertificateCreateWithData(nil, data)!


    let params : [String: Any] = [
        kSecClass as String : kSecClassCertificate,
        kSecValueRef as String : cert,
        kSecAttrLabel as String: "label1",
    ]
    SecItemDelete(params as CFDictionary)
    let status = SecItemAdd(params as CFDictionary, nil)
    print("status1: \(status)")


    let query: [String: Any] = [
        kSecClass as String : kSecClassIdentity,
        kSecReturnRef as String: true,
        kSecAttrLabel as String: "label1"
    ]

    var secIdentity: SecIdentity?
    var extractedData: AnyObject?
    let status2 = SecItemCopyMatching(query as NSDictionary, &extractedData)
    print("status2: \(status2)")

    if (status2 == errSecSuccess) {
        print("success")
        secIdentity = extractedData as! SecIdentity?
    }
```

Log:
`status1: 0
status2: -25300`. Error `-25300` is `errSecItemNotFound`

Here is how info of that given certificate looks like:

`openssl x509 -in cert.cer -text
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 1465898828 (0x575fd74c)
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=LT, L=NamePurposelyHidden, O=NamePurposelyHidden, OU=NamePurposelyHidden, CN=NamePurposelyHidden
        Validity
            Not Before: Aug  9 08:21:03 2014 GMT
            Not After : Jul 27 08:21:03 2064 GMT
        Subject: C=LT, L=NamePurposelyHidden, O=NamePurposelyHidden, OU=NamePurposelyHidden, CN=NamePurposelyHidden
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:b6:26:54:85:05:15:bd:2f:af:39:c0:91:41:05:
                    d2:35:74:bf:d2:e5:35:2d:3d:21:60:15:6b:d9:f6:
                    66:2b:02:29:c9:94:8b:3c:36:af:f8:5a:05:0f:21:
                    25:7d:90:5b:ab:70:f5:85:e8:ce:8a:60:2b:a4:61:
                    36:a8:b9:16:f6:79:7b:e1:1f:37:83:5b:fd:18:db:
                    70:7a:dd:79:3b:74:0d:4b:4f:4d:49:8c:79:0b:8c:
                    c1:2e:7c:4c:62:ae:b3:e4:b5:cf:4b:20:2c:98:20:
                    4a:4c:dd:49:67:99:7f:c1:dd:39:4d:be:8c:b7:6a:
                    b8:e6:c3:e3:a8:03:21:ec:a3:c8:e4:46:d7:e6:d4:
                    83:4a:5a:d7:a1:35:6f:54:72:96:b2:52:54:37:d4:
                    b4:62:f8:07:eb:27:d5:f0:42:0f:5a:3a:b8:ae:78:
                    38:73:e4:b5:7c:d1:6b:e4:61:6e:fd:df:c8:03:a4:
                    8d:fe:d3:92:98:df:30:fb:e1:03:45:cb:dd:6a:ca:
                    50:25:b2:a6:4b:4a:64:e0:79:a6:ef:35:53:df:d9:
                    48:16:f8:39:08:94:9b:8e:f0:74:01:ae:76:46:9c:
                    9c:a3:ec:70:45:24:44:96:3d:b4:06:51:2e:1e:dd:
                    4d:72:09:0d:9d:f1:11:08:9d:24:4b:5c:3e:79:0b:
                    b9:c7
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                AE:95:DF:CD:E0:D9:BB:D1:8E:CD:15:86:98:9B:04:35:D7:E6:96:44
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         61:d3:98:46:a9:53:db:fc:a9:3b:db:40:40:63:55:7c:66:74:
         35:82:83:c8:19:4a:89:ae:bd:1b:5c:26:8e:20:f9:5b:db:aa:
         0c:4c:99:4e:28:3b:51:00:33:96:5f:22:40:c1:c1:c8:ed:70:
         d7:f7:3e:aa:ec:f9:0e:bb:ec:f8:17:12:c1:49:f6:02:0d:73:
         57:39:48:5d:ad:8f:e5:e9:3b:b1:f8:1d:d4:7e:cf:58:d5:78:
         73:9c:56:3b:bb:3a:25:36:c8:3b:b8:ba:90:97:6e:28:51:5d:
         63:23:3e:90:7d:87:61:13:03:c5:27:1b:51:55:c0:17:76:18:
         1a:74:6d:f9:2c:c8:f1:7a:89:64:41:fc:3b:7b:82:4f:e3:e8:
         5d:02:40:3a:d5:81:f3:38:de:aa:79:53:1a:d2:a3:60:59:94:
         8c:bd:62:bb:6d:70:da:0d:22:3e:9d:e0:fa:5d:20:87:ce:16:
         f0:53:f4:b7:1d:c7:b3:59:64:ba:8a:73:75:bc:7f:61:cb:14:
         d4:9f:34:3f:bd:b1:06:0c:62:f6:1f:b4:d2:15:38:61:bd:2c:
         44:94:1c:e1:88:f4:d2:fc:42:d7:6d:ed:d6:4e:a2:b7:67:20:
         01:7a:87:39:3b:4c:2b:3c:ef:3c:15:54:1d:cc:00:30:9c:cc:
         e2:4f:71:98`

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45997841/how-to-get-a-secidentityref-from-a-seccertificateref-and-a-seckeyref ?

Comment: doesn't seem to

Comment: You can only get a SecIdentityRef if you have both the certificate and private key.  Is the private key already in that keychain?

Comment: @bartonjs hmm, I was given only a .cer file and told it's enough. What private key do I need? Can I generate it somehow to work with the certificate?

Comment: @Gintas_ nope. But you could look at the original file and see if it says “PRIVATE KEY” in it. The PEM could have a private key in addition to the cert.